# How to make an svg rect element have an tooltip with the mac voiceover screen reader?

Tags: d3.js, svg, wai-aria, rect

I've tried adding a title element to the parent group of an svg rect element, and I've tried adding aria-roles and aria-labels to svg rects. But the Mac voiceover software still doesn't read out information about the elements contained in these aria fields when browsing the SVG.

Does anyone know how to render `rect` svg elements so the Mac screen reader reads either title information in their group or specific area information attached to them?

Comment: Do a google search on "accessible svg" and you'll see several suggestions.  However, svg is not well supported by screen readers (VoiceOver, JAWS, NVDA) yet.

Comment: @slugolicious I've done a ton of Googling but couldn't get this to work. Tried many ways.

Comment: yeah, support for svg by screen readers isn't great.  you may not find a solution.